# How to reset the angular js calculated field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form where, the values of two fields are calculated using AngularJS Binding. And, I'm also using jquery *Reset()* method to reset my form.

When using the jquery reset the 'Model' values becomes null; but, the calculated field still remains.

When I manually change the the 'Model' values to '0', the calculated values change.

I tried to change the values of the 'Model' via JS to '0'. But, still the calculated values do not change.

**Code Snippet**

*html form*

```
   <form id="form1">
      <div ng-app="">
         <input type="text" ng-model="Parmale" required/>
         <input type="text" ng-model="Parfemale" required/>
         <input type="text" value="{{(Parmale-0)+(Parfemale-0)}}/>
       </div>
      </form>
```

*JS*

```
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
```

Can someone please guide me through?

If this question seems ridiculous, please bear with me! I'm just a student trying to learn.

Comment: Are you wanting to persist the calculated value to your model?

Comment: Ahh. No.. I wanted the values of the calculated to field to reset with accordance to the change of values in the model inputboxes. When i manually change it, the change is reflected. But, when I'm using jquery reset function. The Calculated fields still shows the sum of the earlier values.

Comment: I have achieved what i wanted. But, if you know a cleaner and better way to do the same, then please explain. And, do you know why it didnt work when i used `<input type="text" value="{{(Parmale-0)+(Parfemale-0)}}/>` instead of `<input type="text" ng-model="(Parmale-0)+(Parfemale-0)" />` ??

Comment: Typically you'd fire a model update from a ng-change directive on the inputs rather than set the model to a calculation.  Here's a quick plunker that will show you both the html and javascript for what I'm describing.  https://plnkr.co/edit/oguMsyqGf90cAsSCAYmx?p=preview

Comment: I'm relatively new to angular. I havent still gone through all of its tuts online. I understand what you have done in _app.js_ file but do not fully know what the syntaxes do.  Thanks for the guidance! :)

Comment: I figured it might be ahead of where your learning has take you but thought I'd throw it out there just so you'd know where you should be heading.  Happy learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following line

```
<input type="text" value="{{(Parmale-0)+(Parfemale-0)}} />
```

to

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Parmale+Parfemale" />
```

and since you are doing mathematical operation i would recommend use input type number, etc. appropriate to your requirement.

Regards.

Comment: This doesnt work! When i use `<input type="text" ng-model="Parmale+Parfemale" />` it ConCats up both the numbers, considering it as string.  And, changing the input type to number doesnt show anything at all.

Comment: Sure addition doesn't work with string. So i recommended to use number and it will work as expected.

Comment: I have fixed this issue. by substracting both values with '0' and then adding it.  `<input type="text" ng-model="(Parmale-0)+(Parfemale-0)" />`

Comment: Haha... It sure did! Thanks!!